# simpleError in dim.data.table(obj): object 'Cdm' not found

Tags: r, package, data.table, devtools

I am developing a package. The packages passes R CMD CHECK with no errors, warnings or notes. However, sporadically, when I Build & Reload in RStudio I get 13 lines of output to the console.

```
library(mypackage)
<simpleError in dim.data.table(obj): object 'Cdim' not found>
<simpleError in dim.data.table(obj): object 'Cdim' not found>
<simpleError in dim.data.table(obj): object 'Cdim' not found>
<simpleError in dim.data.table(obj): object 'Cdim' not found>
<simpleError in dim.data.table(obj): object 'Cdim' not found>
<simpleError in dim.data.table(obj): object 'Cdim' not found>
<simpleError in dim.data.table(obj): object 'Cdim' not found>
<simpleError in dim.data.table(obj): object 'Cdim' not found>
<simpleError in dim.data.table(obj): object 'Cdim' not found>
<simpleError in dim.data.table(obj): object 'Cdim' not found>
<simpleError in dim.data.table(obj): object 'Cdim' not found>
<simpleError in dim.data.table(obj): object 'Cdim' not found>
<simpleError in dim.data.table(obj): object 'Cdim' not found>
```

I have 11 objects in `sysdata.rda` but there **are** 13 objects created in a `data-raw` R script which combine to form the 11 objects. All these objects are `data.table`s. (And the changes I've made since seeing this message were to modify those objects). What is causing this error?

The branch is at https://github.com/HughParsonage/grattan/tree/medicareLevyFamilies . I'm not sure how to give a minreprex for this (particularly as it only happens occasionally).

Comment: Please ensure you are able to reproduce it on latest development version. I remember some commits that might have been related to that.